# Get source code of user-defined class and functions?

Tags: php, reflection, introspection

Is there a method for getting the source code of a class or method? I'm looking at the [ReflectionClass](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php), but I don't see one.

Comment: You can open the file and parse using php to get it.

Comment: Check here- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026690/reconstruct-get-code-of-php-function

Comment: I was hoping I could avoid reading in the file...but oh well. I just have to hope that the class/function doesn't start on the same line as some other code.

Answer (score 9):

Best I could come up with:

```
$class = new ReflectionClass($c);
$fileName = $class->getFileName();
$startLine = $class->getStartLine()-1; // getStartLine() seems to start after the {, we want to include the signature
$endLine = $class->getEndLine();
$numLines = $endLine - $startLine;

if(!empty($fileName)) {
    $fileContents = file_get_contents($fileName);
    $classSource = trim(implode('',array_slice(file($fileName),$startLine,$numLines))); // not perfect; if the class starts or ends on the same line as something else, this will be incorrect
    $hash = crc32($classSource);
}
```

**Edit:** This doesn't work well with classes defined like this:

```
class Foo { }
```

Says this is 2 lines long when it should only be 1...

Comment: $numLines = $endLine - $startLine + 1;