# Compare a function with another function

Tags: php, function, compare

I made a function which is contain an include file,
Can I compare this function with other function ?

e.g.

in a.php

```
<?php
$a = "this is file";
?>
```

in b.php

```
<?php
$b = "this is file";
?>
```

in function.php

```
<?php
function a(){
include("a.php");
}

function b(){
include ("b.php");
}

/*
my question is can I compare between function a() and function b() ?
like this
*/

if(a()==b()){
echo "it's same words";
}
else
{echo "not same words";}

?>
```

I know there's simple way to do my case, but it's just an example,
and I want use this way to do my complicated algorithm.

Regards.

Nur Haryadi

Comment: Your functions need to return something. Then you can compare what they return.

Comment: Look this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7905841/get-source-code-of-user-defined-class-and-functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think this way: When does two functions are equal? When their results with same parameters returns same values. It means your functions needs to return something.

```
function a() {
    ob_start();
    include("a.php");

    return ob_get_clean();
}


function b() {
    ob_start();
    include("b.php");

    return ob_get_clean();
}

if (strcmp(a(), b()) == 0) {
    echo "it's same words";
}
```

Comment: `a.php` and `b.php` don't echo anything, so there's nothing in the output buffer. They just set a variable.

Comment: Thanks for your response Justinas, but how about I have more than 2 functions ? like c(), d(), e(), ... etc ?, my case is if there's many same word it will print one word, but I use my Source like this. Many Thanks and Best regards ...

Comment: Barmar : yes, it's true, my bad is, I echo  something ini a.php and b.php

Comment: @nurharyadi Maybe try using different logic to see if variable is set and contains some value?

Comment: @Justinas, My problem was solve for this one , can I ask an answer which is be related with this one ? I forgot to said that, my function in the loop algorithm. many thanks...

Answer (score 1):

You need to put `return` statements in the functions.

```
function a() {
    include("a.php");
    return $a;
}

function b() {
    include("b.php");
    return $b;
}
```

Then you can use

```
if (a() == b())
```

to see if they returned the same thing.

Comment: I have use return, but it can't altough it's in if statement. but, I try this one again. Thanks Mr. Barmar for your help, regards...