# How to get the actual code text in a specific php class function?

Tags: php, regex

I want to get the actual programming code text from a specific function in a file. 
For example, I want to get the code inside `__construct(){}` inside the class called `Example` in `ExampleClass.php`. How can I do that?

Is regex the best way to do this or is there a better way?

Comment: Code snippet? Have you tried anything?

Comment: This answer may help you out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026690/reconstruct-get-code-of-php-function

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026690/reconstruct-get-code-of-php-function

Comment: You mean you want to access the actual code information at runtime in PHP?

Comment: Thanks @Stony and Explosion. Does that example work for class functions as well? It says in the docs: "ReflectionFunction will not work on class methods - instance or static."

Comment: `ReflectionMethod` will work on class methods.