# Is there a way to output a function's code just like javascript does?

Tags: php

I wanted to see what a function does, and I thought of looking at it just like how I find scripts in javascript

I'm looking for something that does the same as javascript's

```
function sampleFn() {
    return 'I am a sample'
}

console.log(sampleFn)
//function sampleFn() {
//    return 'I am a sample'
//}
```

I tried to do

```
print sampleFn;
echo sampleFn;
print_r(sampleFn);
//sampleFn

var_dump(sampleFn);
//string(11) "the_content"
```

I just want to know if there is a way to do it the same way javascript console.log() a function out

Comment: Does this answer your question? [reconstruct/get code of php function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026690/reconstruct-get-code-of-php-function)

Comment: yes! that's what I'm looking for. it's a bit verbose than I was expecting though, but it works

Answer (score 0):

To print the return value of a function, you need to call it like this:

```
echo sampleFn();
```

or

```
var_dump(sampleFn());
```

Please refer the PHP official documentation:

> https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can ! And you were really close.

You can either use `var_dump` or `echo`, but you must add the parenthesis after you function name.

Example:

```
function sampleFn() {
    return "sample!";
}

var_dump(sampleFn());
```