# Get function definition in string form in PHP

Tags: php, vercel, kirby

We have a function that is being defined on a host but not locally which is causing a name collision. The function is `go()` and it's in [Kirby](https://getkirby.com) and somewhere else. When we deploy to [Vercel](https://vercel.com/) we get an error saying `go()` is already defined. This is not an issue locally or on other hosts (we tried Dreamhost as an example).

We tried this to find where the original is called:

```
$reflFunc = new ReflectionFunction('function_name');
print $reflFunc->getFileName() . ':' . $reflFunc->getStartLine();
```

But we get literally: `:`

As if it's not defined. If we wrap the function in `if (!function_exists('go'))` it does break for other reasons but the redeclaration error is alleviated so we know the function exists but we can't find it.

In JavaScript you can do like `console.log(someFunction)` and it'll output the function in string form. Example:

[image]

Can we do this in PHP? This would allow us to try to at least search for the code signature in the project or on the web to find what code is colliding.

Comment: You might be able to use reflection for this. https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionfunction.php or possibly this post will help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026690/reconstruct-get-code-of-php-function

Comment: Yeah I agree but with the code above we get no output. We can try that specific code though but seems really similar to ours

Comment: Honestly the reflection code is not well documented and a little annoying to use sometimes. I would try the exact code in the post to see if it can work at all.

Comment: Check if you have `auto_prepend_file` enabled, that may be where it's defined.

Answer (score 0):

I thought the go function was in an extension so your way to do it with ReflectionFunction was not found. The ReflectionFunction class has lots of get functions to get information about the function, you can call all of them to see more information and maybe luckily smile at you.

I tried a function `mysqli_query` in the mysql extension and it didn't find filename or fileline either but it gave me the function list when I called `$ref->getExtension();`